# Plastic wrap effect

Tags: c++, image-manipulation

Where may I get algorithms to apply a plastic wrapping effect to an image?

I am using Visual C++.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "plastic wrapping"?

Answer (score 1):

This [previous question touches base on similar image distortion effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225548/resources-for-image-distortion-algorithms) and the groundwork for the effects, as far as your particular request, I do not know of any direct source

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055802/cement-effect-artistic-effect

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do something like a CD case or some other simple shrink wrap effect, it's usually done with a semi-transparent image overlay on top of the original image.